# Google recaptcha disappears after second click in the signup button on navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha

In my website recaptcha disappears after second click in sign up button or home button in top navbar. User can signup without verification. How to solve it.

```
<h2>Create Blog</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), class: "form-horizontal" ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :username, required: true, autofocus: true, hint: 'no special characters, no numbers only letters [a-z]' %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    <div id="g-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcOGEgUAAAAAOxXmBxxxxxxxx"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Create Blog", data: { disable_with: "This may take upto 2 minutes... "} %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<script>
  var captcha_interval;
  var myCallback=function(){
    document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].disabled=false;
  };
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].disabled=true;
    grecaptcha.render(
     document.getElementById('g-recaptcha'),
     {
       callback: myCallback,
       sitekey: "6LcOGEgUAAAAAOxXmBVgxxxxxx"
     });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: What code you have written in controller? to check captcha is valid or not

Comment: I think there is no or can't find such codes, How to search it in project. Means search for any definite words?

Comment: Yes , it was handled by javascript. No need to to search for controller., I am checking the problem

Comment: I didn't set recaptcha secret key(can't find where to set). Is that the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render for multiple widgets</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        alert(response);
      };
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('example3', {
          'sitekey' : '6LcOGEgUAAAAAOxXmBVgxxxxxx',
          'callback' : verifyCallback,
          'theme' : 'dark'
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- POSTs back to the page's URL upon submit with a g-recaptcha-response POST parameter. -->
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="example3"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As per reference [google-captcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display), you are missing the

> ```
>     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
>         async defer>
>     </script>
> ```

after the form.

Please try adding after form and let me know

Comment: It is present before </head> portion, do I need to change it to after the code?

Comment: The issue may be with java script written  to disable and enable the button, apply it properly by inspecting the function. It will work

Comment: I think it is working now I changed position of `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>` It was messed up with cloudflare js file\